# C binary code (after compilation) to EVM bytecode conversion

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bytecode, smartcontracts, evm

Consider the following example:

Suppose I have a function ADD written in C language that adds two integers int A and int B and returns the sum C. 
Now, I want to verify that my function ADD worked correctly using the Ethereum blockchain.

To do so, I deployed a simple smart contract on the Ethereum blockchain that has a function called *Verify* ((A,B),C) that returns true if verification holds, false otherwise. 
For this verification, I want to pass two parameters to the Verify function. The first parameter should be the inputs and the second parameter will be the output of my ADD function.

The *Verify* function will be executed on (A,B), generate output C' and compare it with C. If C'== C, return true, else return false. 
Now, for the above example, my question is following:

1. How to translate the compiled binary code of my C program to EVM code? In other words, if I consider (A,B,0) as state 1 output and (A,B,C) as state 2 output of my program in C, then **how can I convert each state to EVM bytecode** so that, EVM start execution from state1 and ends at state2?